# Add To Source Control Recursively in UCM Project

Tags: android

how can i add files (add to source control) recursively using commandline in UCM Project.
last time i tried i've failed using the BaseClearcase's commandline ....

i use this command line:
clearfsimport -recurse -c [comment] [file location path] [vob path]

and then there was error message shown:
"must be in an activity UCM ..."

Rational ClearCase
- RCC v7.1.2
- Windows Server

please help.
thanks.

Comment: You need to provide the commands you used and the error message you received. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

"must be in an activity UCM ..." (full message would be helpful) probably means that no activity has been set for the active view when trying to perform checkin/checkout/add to source control. You must set an activity first using the setactivity command. 
See also https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm